# User input sanitisation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to sanitise user input (or output) for a web app I'm developing. The user input is just plain text, and I want to prevent HTML or other "harmful" strings. However characters such as less than, greater than, apostrophes, ampersands, quotes, etc., *should* be allowed.

I guess the first step is to disable request validation to prevent the generic "a potentially dangerous value was detected" message, but what else do I need to do? I can't simply htmlencode the output otherwise I'll end up with &lt being displayed in place of a less than character, for example.

Are there any tools that can help? I had a quick look at the AntiXSS library but from what I've seen it's just a glorified htmlencoder, or am I missing something? What about MVC - does this have anything built in?

I've never found a decent article on this kind of thing. Some say to sanitise input, while others say to sanitise output, and examples are typically over-simplistic, using techniques like htmlencoding, which will reformat perfectly valid characters such as a less than.

Comment: +1 for you actually caring about sanitization. Too many developers skip it due to laziness.

Comment: @JonAdams I've been guilty of it myself, mainly because I find it so difficult. In the past I've used overly-simplistic solutions, only to find that *Ryan O'Murphy* contacts the helpdesk because his apostrophe has been stripped out or changed to the string "&apos"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Anti-XSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) is the standard library in ASP.Net WebForms for now. Though it is sub optimal. And the latest version ([4.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589)) has [several breaking bugs](http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289#ReviewsAnchor) that haven't been fixed in awhile.

Also see the MSDN article [Information Security - Anti-Cross Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx).

See [Should I use the Anti-XSS Security Runtime Engine in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003736/2291) for your answer regarding MVC. From that answer:

> Phil Haack has an interesting blog post here
>   http://haacked.com/archive/2009/02/07/take-charge-of-your-security.aspx.
>   He suggests using Anti-XSS combined with CAT.NET.